# Why do my pictures in a asp image control look squashed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an asp.net c# web page. On the page I have a image box which will randomly display an image every 5 secs or so. The problem is, some of the pictures appear squashed. All of the pictures have been cropped in photoshop to 350x350 pixels and the size of the image box is 350x350 pixles. If you look at the pictures using another program they look fine, but on the asp.net page they look funny. Can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Craig

here's the source code rendered in IE, but it looks nothing like what I have in my asp.net default page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>
    Home Page
</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE5NTc5Mjg4MDYPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICAw9kFgICAw8WAh4HRW5hYmxlZGdkZESHdPrJrv0fd90yot44IdP2LuG176cv2XyHWiPVlPSh" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=DogTP9ciF8js-919lyE5BNUR3gLIy6vQ94IA8ujQqufPbSjgjYs-MB8TFhgGkZbCezg2T7MihOn_QzXNJh8bUbKXvUZPuDq-Zo79nPbUosQ1&amp;t=634856347325009875" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=4jTc4W6vHbFONhMZfZEniQ0ll2ox3vAxSkMzYB-7HtakDqsmhXCZFBXSRwOb1nRWK6CMzP0qyRYdnYMNnTFXhx2r0J9E2ik7kM8XVmq_UBEPDXqK-kLCJqvRQAvq0wv0ZlWQS1gCjlQxcxLhV1XrJQ2&amp;t=150492e7" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=GHu6blHeASt9skHbsJx4uFWYiLKvlA8B1V1ZT8jJM7xJFl3ycZATlv3IHRrGJMm_fpPlBSBh8s1B1E7r9viSf2_vG2Xab8vHZGZqr8izsLUD5pjhbTenZ9dImmZEGONdwrT5ungX3KYzAap2ByhMGQe1RCN4HIeWzLfx9QPaNIL_dFC2Su5ez5Ui0Ux0TCBs0&amp;t=ffffffff940d030f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=k0ZMcbO229cP7tJHdqfAeLLkubS_PB3nLJRGVfbZzo992j-U0QXogHZ9AeLO7yXzYa70OSzRIw-wnFwxHbCbmy30q_MrEaY-iqOTNAQzXLCt0hz--HUsMHJsrrht6bk34EjhwJc7bL5h2KjWTMIm5sDlaERrkzNMJ2CYN7WaxPRUTRyOkbTPleHmC1PMtedi0&amp;t=ffffffff940d030f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=7Pyyv_WcNl6DPXEjw9wnwQXSTOHSqlXve9fO2VxG4I-t0REk8QlK5V7QxKS7jkGO1CGno7PDXkPN1ApWod5KVH--pObLgj1ukjWVTcpKZZNJKm_Fz0qDQd_RVd2qBcBGOEo0qqVjh1A8QaUZNRMFCx12FzcYFbkEV_4FAwoZHekJoj0b0U3QdytSO2iP-U-F0&amp;t=ffffffff940d030f" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                   My Family Web Site
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/WebResource.axd?d=CEw_ah6x15SB8gE6w0h-5pVp-C_glYrwEoXIAM74CoVRv4LUELJEQWVkcLYtMPI0-_6jQVupgDDSAEIK43VxSf5HH-tcHYeqNWJ2d0U1yuU1&amp;t=634856347325009875" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="About.aspx">About</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Daniel.aspx">Daniel</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">

    <h2>
        Welcome To The Smith Family Web Site</h2>
    <p>
        Here you can find out all of the great things going on at the homestead.
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$MainContent$ScriptManager1', 'ctl01', ['tctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1','MainContent_UpdatePanel1'], ['ctl00$MainContent$Timer1','MainContent_Timer1'], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>

    <div class="picture"> 
        <span id="MainContent_Timer1" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"></span>
        <div id="MainContent_UpdatePanel1">

                <img id="MainContent_Image1" src="Pictures/25.JPG" align="middle" style="height:350px;width:350px;" />

</div>

    </div>


        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._Timer, {"enabled":true,"interval":1500,"uniqueID":"ctl00$MainContent$Timer1"}, null, null, $get("MainContent_Timer1"));
});
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code in my asp.net page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FamilyWebSite._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome To The Smith Family Web Site</h2>
    <p>
        Here you can find out all of the great things going on at the homestead.
    </p>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="picture"> 
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1500">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Pictures/25.JPG" 
                    Width="350px" Height="350px" ImageAlign="Middle" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

here's the Site.css as well

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #fff;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

p
{
    color: #fff;
}
/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 800px;
    background-color: #778899;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;   
    border: 2px ridge #787878;




}

.header h1
{
    width: auto;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    color: Olive;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;    
    background: #000;



}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:Olive;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 2px 2px 2px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px groove #fff;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.picture
{
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 3px ridge #fff;
    height: auto;
    width: inherit;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Post the source code rendered in your browser

Comment: Have you tried removing the reference to the `site.css` and check if the images look fine?

Comment: no, I don't think that there's anything there that would change the size of the picture

Comment: put that in an answer, the 2px padding in the .picture class was throwing off the picture size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler wasn't seeing the edited picture files. A clean rebuild refreshed the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the height and width to asp image tag. As the pictures are already cropped in photoshop to 350x350. asp image tag will render the image with original height and width.